# Texture not as preview

Tags: rendering, materials

It's the first time I've tried using a texture and after a couple of hours, I cannot find what I'm doing wrong.  Help.  It looks fine in the preview, and looks bad rendered.  I"ve tried lights.  Ideas?  [image: Cork Material UI]

[image]

Comment: The link Duarte provides does provide an explanation.  Solved it for me.  I don't understand why someone got upset with my pointing it out.

Comment: The answer section is meant for full comprehensive answers explaining the process. Link only answers are discouraged, if the link goes down the answer becomes empty and useless for any future visitors. I'd encourage expanding our answer to include a short explanation of the issue and how you solved it